# Reinit UIImage is it possible?

Tags: ios, uiimage

I'm confused a little bit. 
I have a property UIImage *myImage in my view controller. In view did load i do:

`myImage = [UIImage imageWithName:@"white.png"];`

When I come back to this controller after some another controller in viewWillAppear occurs next:

`myImage = [UIImage imageWithName:@"black.png"];`

But image doesn't change when I show it on view controller's imageview. It's still white.
Is it possible to reinit image with another image?
Thanks for attention!

Comment: I see one solution: instead of UIImage use UIImageView and use:
[myImageView setNeedToDisplay];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"white"]];

 imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"black"]];
```

try like this..

Answer (score 0):

```
 imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white"]];

 imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"black"]];
```

It should be like this